# Vaadin - productionMode on Spring Boot customized Servlet

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-spring-boot

I'm trying to put my project in production mode, but no luck :(

Everything appears to be fine on startup logs:

```
2017-01-09 09:26:24.453  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Registering Vaadin servlet
2017-01-09 09:26:24.453  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Servlet will be mapped to URLs [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
2017-01-09 09:26:24.469  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Setting servlet init parameters
2017-01-09 09:26:24.469  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [productionMode] = [true]
2017-01-09 09:26:24.470  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [resourceCacheTime] = [3600]
2017-01-09 09:26:24.470  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [heartbeatInterval] = [60]
2017-01-09 09:26:24.470  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [closeIdleSessions] = [true]
2017-01-09 09:26:26.260  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Checking the application context for Vaadin UI mappings
2017-01-09 09:26:26.263  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Registering Vaadin servlet of type [com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet]
2017-01-09 09:26:26.273  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Forwarding @SpringUI URLs from {/admin/*=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@6fc3f1a7, /pages/*=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@6fc3f1a7, /dashboard/*=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@6fc3f1a7, /admin/*/=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@6fc3f1a7, /dashboard/*/=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@6fc3f1a7, /pages/*/=org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController@6fc3f1a7}
2017-01-09 09:26:26.283  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider  : Looking up SpringViews
2017-01-09 09:26:26.288  INFO 80996 --- [           main] c.v.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider  : 18 SpringViews found
2017-01-09 09:26:26.858  INFO 80996 --- [           main] com.web.Application   : Started Application in 26.671 seconds (JVM running for 27.124)
```

But when I access my application:

```
2017-01-09 09:26:32.916  WARN 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-1] c.v.s.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration     : 
=================================================================
Vaadin is running in DEBUG MODE.
Add productionMode=true to web.xml to disable debug features.
To show debug window, add ?debug to your application URL.
=================================================================
2017-01-09 09:26:35.613  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Checking the application context for Vaadin UIs
2017-01-09 09:26:35.615  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found Vaadin UI [com.web.ui.AdminUI]
2017-01-09 09:26:35.616  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found Vaadin UI [com.web.ui.DashboardUI]
2017-01-09 09:26:35.616  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found Vaadin UI [com.web.ui.PagesUI]
2017-01-09 09:26:35.616  WARN 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-2] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found no Vaadin UIs in the application context
2017-01-09 09:26:36.737  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-8] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Checking the application context for Vaadin UIs
2017-01-09 09:26:36.740  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-8] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found Vaadin UI [com.web.ui.AdminUI]
2017-01-09 09:26:36.740  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-8] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found Vaadin UI [com.web.ui.DashboardUI]
2017-01-09 09:26:36.740  INFO 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-8] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found Vaadin UI [com.web.ui.PagesUI]
2017-01-09 09:26:36.740  WARN 80996 --- [  XNIO-2 task-8] c.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider  : Found no Vaadin UIs in the application context
```

I'm using a custom servlet for vaadin, if I comment it (and use default provided by vaadin spring boot auto config) no DEBUG information appears...

```
@Bean(name = "springBootServletRegistrationBean")
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        SpringVaadinServlet servlet = new SpringVaadinServlet() {

            @Override
            protected VaadinServletService createServletService(DeploymentConfiguration deploymentConfiguration) throws ServiceException {
                SpringVaadinServletService service = new SpringVaadinServletService(this, deploymentConfiguration, null) {
...
```

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true` to your properties file. All other properties can be seen in class: `com.vaadin.spring.boot.internal.VaadinServletConfigurationProperties`

Also, you should use following structure instead of using `ServletRegistrationBean` for a custom `VaadinServlet`:

```
@Bean
public VaadinServlet vaadinServlet(){
    return new SpringVaadinServlet(){
        @Override
        protected VaadinServletService createServletService(DeploymentConfiguration deploymentConfiguration) throws ServiceException {
            SpringVaadinServletService servletService = new SpringVaadinServletService(this, deploymentConfiguration, getServiceUrlPath()) {
                // Override any custom method here
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Tks for response @bekce, but this is the problem, I already add this line on properties file, and startup logs tell me that it was read as true.

Comment: @Dyorgio I have updated the answer to include the correct way to use custom `VaadinServlet`.

Comment: Perfect @bekce ! I got some problems before up vote this answer because I wasn't using getServiceUrlPath() method (using null).

Comment: @Dyorgio you're welcome :) please also mark the answer as accepted if you think your problem is solved